# Algolia Search PHP API Retrieve ObjectIDs

Tags: php, api, search, algolia

I'm using algolia search's php API to perform a name search.  I would like for it to only return the objectIDs because I want to filter down the matches based on additional (external) criteria.  I added the attributesToRetrieve parameter to the search() both as a string and as an array, but it still returns everything.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

```
$index->search('value', array("attributesToRetrieve" => "objectID"));
```

OR

```
 $index->search('value', array("attributesToRetrieve" => array("objectID")));
```

Comment: Did you also set attributesToHighlight and attributesToSnippet to array() ?

Comment: I set both those to empty strings "" and it suddenly worked.  Go figure!
You got the answer!